# In Javascript, the parsing error occurs. "Unexpected token funds"

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, adobe-brackets, unexpected-token

I'm trying to practice js code. 
In line 1, parsing error occurs. 
I think there's no error(actually the code works), but I want to know what is wrong with my code. 
Thank you.

```
let funds = 50;
let round = 0;

while(funds > 1 && funds < 100){
    round++;
    console.log(`round ${round}: `);
    console.log(`\tstarting funds: ${funds}p`);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "parsing error occurs" and "actually the code works"?

Comment: `funds` is always 50. So, this is an infinite loop. Did you intend to increment `funds` in the loop as well?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović  In my code editor, there's an alert says "parsing error: unexpected", and the code above is part of my full code. The code runs successfully in console.

Comment: @adiga I'm sorry, the code above is one part of my code. I've made a mistake when tried to upload my code simple.

Comment: Does your code editor support ES6 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Comment: That is because lack of `}` or `)` or other closing character in previous lines...go through the lines before and see if you missed any closing character

Comment: @NikkoKhresna — What previous lines? The OP said the error occurred on line 1.

Comment: @Quentin according to OP's previous comment, *"the code above is one part of my code"*. So, this is probably not a mcve

Comment: @adiga I'm searching for it. My code editor is Brackets, and I don't think this support ES6 template.

Comment: @Quentin I copied and pasted the code above at the new file, and the same error occurs. I think prev lines doesn't effect at this situation.

Comment: @Jinne as Quentin mentioned, this is an issue with your IDE, Brackets. Not the code itself.

Comment: @adiga Yeah I can see it. Thank you for answering. :)

Comment: yeah modern IDE with syntax checker does that lol :)

Answer (score 1):

`let` is a relatively new feature in JavaScript.

The syntax checker in your editor does not recognise it, so it treats it as a variable name.

Since `someVarName someOtherVarName` is not valid JS, it reports an error.

When you run the code in the console, you are using a JS engine which understands `let` so it doesn't error there.

---

You might want to configure your editor to use a different syntax checker, or switch editors to one that you can do that with. I use [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) which can be configured to support (or reject) many features of JavaScript depending on your target platforms.

Comment: Could be template literal as well

Comment: @adiga — Not when the error is reported on line 1 (it will probably choke on the template literal too, but it doesn't seem to be getting that far).

Comment: I think I have to change code editor. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Jinne — You said you were using Brackets. It supports ESLint. You probably just need an eslint configuration file in the root of your project folder.